# Changing Watir scripts to Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am just starting to learn Ruby and Watir/Watir-Webdriver.  I started a job that already has working Watir test scripts.  However, I need to use Water-Webdriver for the new web applications

My question is: What is needed to convert these scripts to a Webdriver version?  Or is it so much work that it is better to start from scratch?  Any references to docs that help with this would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to answer that question without having a good look at all your code. However, I can say that it won't be a long, involved process. Just install the watir-webdriver gem, then change

```
require 'watir'
```

to

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

and fix any issues, if there are any (and there may not be).

Comment: There's no need to switch away from `watir` gem because it allows to choose drivers as necessary - https://github.com/watir/watir#switching-between-drivers

Comment: That's awesome to know!

Answer (score 0):

WAtir only supports IE browser where as watir-webdriver supports all the browsers. It is an extension of the Selenium webdriver. Also most of the methods in the Watir are supported in watir-webdriver,but you may need to check the rubydocs for more on those